# How to take command line file input in Perl from user?

Tags: perl, command-line, perl-module

How to take command line file input in Perl from user ?

```
my $filename = 'devices.xml'; 
my $filename1= 'discoveryinstances.xml';
```

Instead of using the static location of XMLfiles, Can i get a dynamic XML location from the user which may be in some other directory ?

```
use XML::LibXML;
use XML::XPath;
use XML::XPath::XMLParser;
print "Enter the file location for devices.xml file"."\n";
my $firstfile =<STDIN>;
my $filename = chomp($firstfile);
print "Enter the file location for discoveryinstances.xml file"."\n";
my $secondfile =<STDIN>;
my $filename1=chomp($secondfile);
```

solution for this was :

```
print "Enter the location:\n";
chomp( my $filename = <STDIN> );
```

Comment: Command-line arguments are exposed in the [`@ARGV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables) array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the full path of file location to use in perl program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18526762/how-do-i-get-the-full-path-of-file-location-to-use-in-perl-program)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use this to take multiple input from the user

```
my @filename = <STDIN>;
```

In the array of filename u have all the files names that the user have given

For fixed 2 files

```
my $firstfile =<STDIN>;
my $secondfile =<STDIN>;
```

Now u have both the files

Comment: If i implement using this functionality, Can i redirect my output to  a text file ?

Comment: ya u can do this ..take input from the user if u want only two files .then create two scalar variable .and store the files and use them

Comment: try this one and let me know if u need further help .this is the simple way

Comment: C:\Users\dudmo01\Desktop\PERL\test>perl -w temp2.pl
Enter the file location for devices.xml file
"C:\Users\dudmo01\Desktop\PERL\test\devices.xml"
Enter the file location for discoveryinstances.xml file
"C:\Users\dudmo01\Desktop\PERL\test\discoveryinstances.xml"

Enter the device I.D to look out for I.P Address
Cannot open file '1' at C:/Perl64/site/lib/XML/XPath.pm line 53, <STDIN> line 2.

Comment: `use XML::LibXML;
use XML::XPath;
use XML::XPath::XMLParser;
print "Enter the file location for devices.xml file"."\n";
my $firstfile =<STDIN>;
my $filename = chomp($firstfile);
print "Enter the file location for discoveryinstances.xml file"."\n";
my $secondfile =<STDIN>;
my $filename1=chomp($secondfile);`

Comment: not the complete one , but the input functionality has covered in that part of code.

Comment: perldoc -f chomp – the return value of chomp is useless: it returns the number of characters returned from the string. The argument is modified, so you could do

Answer (score 1):

Use this module, [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) - Extended processing of command line options.
This is best module for command line options.

example like

```
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;
use Data::Dumper;
my %args;
GetOptions( \%args, "filename1=s"
                  , "filename2=s"
           ) or die "Invalid Options \n";

print Dumper(\%args);
```

Run program like :

```
abc.pl -filename1 "abc.xml" -filename2 "test.xml"
```

Comment: In Getopt::Long we have multiple options of taking arguments but i just need to take the input file location.Nothing more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the $ARGV collection to read the command line arguments.

Comment: Can u give me any examples to implement that?