# How do I get the full path of file location to use in perl program?

Tags: xml, perl, xpath, perl-module

```
use XML::LibXML; 
use XML::XPath; 
use XML::XPath::XMLParser;
print "Enter the file location for devices.xml file"."\n";
my $firstfile =<STDIN>;
my $filename = chomp($firstfile); 
print "Enter the file location for discoveryinstances.xml file"."\n";
my $secondfile =<STDIN>; my $filename1=chomp($secondfile);
```

How to query for a file location in Perl from the user command prompt ?

Comment: [perldoc -f chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) – the return value of `chomp` is useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[perldoc -f chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) – the return value of `chomp` is useless: it returns the number of characters returned from the string. The argument is modified, so you could do

```
print "Enter the location:\n";
chomp( my $filename = <STDIN> );
...
```

Comment: very useful tip. Which solved my error.